# ASP .NET Core MVC: как правильно использовать Partial View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с проблемой вызова Partial View.

Имеем модель:

```
public class File
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }

        public int? PhoneId { get; set; }        
    }
```

Контроллер для отображения Partial View:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetAdditionalPhotos(int phoneId)
        {
            using (db)
            {
                var model = db.Files.Where(f => f.PhoneId == phoneId).ToList();

                return PartialView("_GetAdditionalPhotos", model);
            }                        
        }
```

Так выглядит PartialView (_GetAdditionalPhotos.cshtml):

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.File>

<table id="table" data-toggle="table" data-search="false" data-virtual-scroll="true">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-width="100">Фото</th>            
            <th data-width="120"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var photo in Model)
        {            
            <tr>
                <td><img src="@Url.Content(@photo.Path)" width="80" height="80" /></td>               
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

В основном View пробую вызвать Partial View:

```
        <div class="col col-sm-12" id="additionalPhotos">            
            @if (Model.Files != null)
            {

                @await Html.PartialAsync("_GetAdditionalPhonePhotos", Model.Id)

            }
            else
            {
                <p>Нет дополнительных фотографий</p>
            }
        </div>
```

Но получаю ошибку:

InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Int32', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Models.File]'.

С указанной проблемой разобрался - необходимо передавать в PartialView модель.

Но теперь появился дополнительный вопрос - в основном View я обрабатываю событие нажатия на кнопку и выполняю js-скрипт для обновления Partial View. Но как мне теперь передавать модель?

Вот код обработки скриптом события:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetAdditionalPhotos", "Home", new { Model })';
    $("#btnReloadAdditionalPhotos").click(function () {
        $('#additionalPhotos').load(url);
    });
</script>
```

Но модель не принимается :(

Comment: В ошибке же все написано вы передаете `@await Html.PartialAsync("_GetAdditionalPhonePhotos", Model.Id)` --> `The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Int32'...`, а задекларировали получить `...a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Models.File]'.`

Answer (score 1):

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Int32', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Models.File]'.

Эта ошибка выводится из-за того, что при вызове метода `Html.PartialAsync` происходит "рендер" только `razor` страницы (в вашем случае `_GetAdditionalPhotos.cshtml`), а действие `public ActionResult GetAdditionalPhotos(int phoneId)` никогда не выполняется. Поэтому и получается, что вы передаете `int id`, сразу в вашу вьюху, которая ожидает список `File`.

Раньше в `ASP.NET MVC` для этих целей существовал метод `Action`/`RenderAction`, и в отличии от `Html.PartialAsync`, он делал вызов вашего экшена, который принимает `id` и выполняет нужный код. Сейчас этого нет, но добавили [View Component](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Например:

`Views/Shared/Components/PhotoViewComponent.cs`:

```
public class PhotoViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public PhotoViewComponent(DbContext db) { /* ... */ }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        using (db)
        {
            var model = db.Files.Where(f => f.PhoneId == phoneId).ToList();

            return View(model);
        } 
    }
}
```

Вашу `_GetAdditionalPhotos.cshtml` нужно поместить и переименовать в `Views/Shared/Components/Photo/Default.cshtml` (это не обязательно делать, но тогда в компоненте нужно будет явно передавать название вьюхи).

И рендерить теперь это можно так: `@await Component.InvokeAsync("Photo")`.

А если добавить `Tag Helper` в `_ViewImports.cshtml`: `@addTagHelper *, <название вашей сборки>`, то рендерить его можно будет при помощи тега: `<vc:photo></vc:photo>`.

Comment: По факту мне нужно обновлять Partial View по событию нажатия на кнопку в основном View. Я пробую это делать через js - добавил информацию об этом в основной вопрос. Смогу ли я из js вызывать @await Component.InovkeAsync? Или может подскажете как передать Модель через Url.Action в контроллер - как я пытаюсь это сделать.

Comment: ни `Html.PartialAsync`, ни `Component.InovkeAsync` из JS работать не будут, для этого нужно делать экшн, который возвращает PartialView, как у вас, а его уже рендерить на стороне клиента, через `@Url.Action`

Comment: например, так `@Url.Action("GetAdditionalPhotos", "Home", new { phoneId = 1 })`, т.к. ваш экшен принимает id, его и нужно передавать

Comment: Понял! Премного Вам благодарен. Получается, что мне нужно вызывать не `@await Html.PartialAsync`, а `Url.Action` в обоих ситуациях (из JS и из Razor-кода на основном View). Так сказать, забыть о PartialView. Но может тогда будет реален вариант использования InvokeAsync и его обновлять по событию обновления модели?

Comment: `Url.Action` все лишь возвращает ссылку, которую кто-то должен вызвать/открыть, поэтому в razor скорее всего она будет вам бесполезна, а если вы решили уже решили делать загрузку через js, то зачем обычная? пользователь открыл страницу, а потом js загрузил все что нужно, тогда partial view можно вообще не использовать, а передавать только нужную инфу как json

Comment: Сейчас ситуация следующая: пользователь заходит на страницу и при ее рендеринге отрабатывает PartialAsync отображая блок с списком, но на этой же странице есть кнопка "Обновить", по нажатию которой должна обновляться информация в этом Partial View. Собственно это пока и нужно. Но не могу пока передать модель в которой есть свойство с типом другой модели через Url.Action из js обрабатывающего событие нажатия на кнопку. :(